# One of two practically identical UITapGestureRecognizers acting much slower than the other

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uislider, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have 2 almost identical tap gestures like so:

```
let minusGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("minusSlider:"))
minusGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
downArrowImageView.addGestureRecognizer(minusGesture)

let plusGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("plusSlider:"))
plusGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
upArrowImageView.addGestureRecognizer(plusGesture)
```

They trigger practically identical actions like so:

```
func minusSlider(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if mySlider.value > mySlider.minimumValue {
        mySlider.value -= 1
    }
}

func plusSlider(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if mySlider.value < mySlider.maximumValue {
        mySlider.value += 1
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot for context. Basically tapping the respective arrow moves the slider value up or down by 1.

[image]

When I tap the up arrow, it's very responsive. I can tap rapidly and it works properly. However, when I tap the down arrow, it triggers the action achingly slow. It only works if I tap really slow. If I tap at a quicker pace it's very unresponsive, only working every few taps, and I receive this error the rest of the time:

> <_UISystemGestureGateGestureRecognizer: 0x17d3aac0>: Touch: Failed to receive system gesture state notification before next touch

Why is this error occurring on only the down arrow tap gesture and not the up arrow? There is nothing else that separates these two gestures aside from what I posted above and the fact that they are on opposite edges of my view.

Comment: Why don't you use buttons in place of imageview and tapgestures

Comment: I get the same behavior both ways. Trying to understand why.

Comment: Okie. Now check this way, set maximum value for slider as default and now try with down arrow tap and check its working cool. then try with up arrow and look its behaviour if its lagging or not

Comment: Tried, up arrow works great at all times. Down arrow lags still.

Comment: Have you tried with switching off the multitasking gestures in settings panel

Comment: This is an iPhone app and I can't find instructions on how to do that for iPhone. Even so, I wouldn't expect my users to do that, they should just expect a responsive tap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `- requireGestureRecognizerToFail`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/requireGestureRecognizerToFail:

Or `- gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:

Somehow the minusGesture is getting overriden by other gestures on your view.

Comment: Thanks, it seemed to be overridden by the automatic swipe back to previous view controller in the navigation stack